# Can I set a date field in DB2 to null

Tags: db2

Why does DB2 write 01/01/0001 in the date field when I set it to null?

Can I set that field to NULL. When db2 set it to 01/01/0001 my ado recordset blows up because it is not a valid date.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of DB2 are you using?  As long as the date field is nullable, you can set a date field to null.

Comment: The field might be defined as "Not Null"

Answer (score 0):

You can of course set a date column to a NULL value. How do *you* do that?

Either the client you use is messing with you, or there is a trigger on the table that changes NULL values in that column to the value you see.

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes you can  insert nulls into a date column.  Below is the syntax that works to insert a null value(depending on version).  Timestamp is the column type so you can interchange it with date. Depending on your DB2 version you might have a different method to do it.  This will not work if the field specification of the datetime field was not set to allow nulls.

   INSERT INTO [Table Name](col1, col2, col3)SELECT Value1, Value2, 
   cast(NULL as timestamp) FROM [Source Table]
2. The reason you're seeing 01/01/0001 is because DB2 is attempting to convert the null to a value and 01/01/0001 is the default for a date field.

Comment: Er, no.  If he was getting **errors**, there wouldn't be _anything_ inserted into the table.  While this _is_ the correct syntax for inserting a null value, that doesn't sound like his actual problem (ie, if it's being inserted from an ORM, that usually takes care of the casting).  Some versions of DB2 are also not able to implicitly cast/compare dates and timestamps (!) - probably to avoid questions of local versus global time; if you were specifying timestamp, why not date anyways?  We should have gotten more information, but the comments are likely correct - "defined as `NOT NULL`".

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse you don't know the exact reason his sql is producing an error because he didn't provide what he was using.  I simply answered his questions which depending on his version of DB2/AS400 will work just fine.  I also updated my answer to fully answer all his questions.